# I have a Canadian refugee travel document; do I need a visa to go to Denmark?

Tags: paperwork, refugees

I have a Canadian refugee travel document; do I need a visa to travel to Denmark?

Comment: What is your citizenship? Search engines such as Timatic and IATA typically require citizenship data and travel document type to be entered in order to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at Timatic (the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents) tells me that Denmark accepts travelers holding refugee travel documents without a visa, only if the refugee travel document was issued by an EEA or Schengen state, or if the traveler has a residence permit from Denmark. Canada is not included in this list of countries. You will therefore need to obtain a visa.

Comment: Surely Denmark accepts travelers with residence permits from other Schengen countries, too.

Comment: @phoog One would think so, but I didn't see that in Timatic.

Comment: While, under Schengen rules, a residence permit is different from a visa, you can argue that if you have a residence permit you are de facto not travelling “without a visa”. However, with that logic, the mentioning of a residence permit from Denmark does not make sense, as a residence permit from any other Schengen State can also be used in lieu of a visa.

Comment: Anyway, with a residence permit issued by a Schengen State, there is no need for a Schengen visa, irrespective of nationality.

Comment: @Arne Sure, but the point is that Timatic explicitly made note of having a residence permit from Denmark, but not from other member states.